# Having trouble with mod rewrite non www to www

Tags: mod-rewrite

Can anyone help me with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I am trying to do is create a rewrite rule  that sends you to the www version of a site if you try to connect using the non www version.

The condition works but the rules doesn't, it sends me to http://
Can anyone suggest hoe I can fix this.
I was expecting $1 = everything in the condition above between ^ and $
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `HTTP_HOST`, [it's evil](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host).

Do this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} (.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where `%1` matches the grouping from a previous `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Linus. I tried that but if I fire a non www url at it it sends me to http://www..com/. Also, if the %1 matches the grouping what does the $1 do? Thanks again.

Comment: @Columbo I added an explicit matching for the whole `%{SERVER_NAME}` in my edit. It works now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks again, that has indeed solved the issue for the domain on it's own but if I add a page it doesn't. E.g. www.domain.com/page.php works but domain.com/page.php does not. Does SERVER_NAME (.*) doesn't seem to pick up the path.

Comment: @Columbo That was some sloppy answer I gave. Please see my *repeated* edit.

Comment: Be careful if your domain and vhost has wildcards enabled. Going to ww.blah.org will redirect you to www.ww.blah.org. I'm not aware of any rewriterule not using the complete domain name in this case.

Comment: You are a star. Thanks very much, that works a treat, I'm now going to go away and pick it apart and see why it works and why HTTP_HOST is evil! Cheers Linus.

Comment: @Capsule A repeated redirect to www.www. is eliminated by the first `RewriteCond`.

Comment: @Columbo See, why it's evil [here](http://perfect-co.de/2011/02/why-http_host-is-evil/).